# Automatic Replica Database of mySql database for backup?

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database in my web project. I need to create a replica of my mysql database for backup.
My web interface interacts directly with one database, i need that other backup database to get automatically updated whenever there are some changes in main or master database.

How can I automate this process of backup database ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run a cron periodically to check for changes. If there is a change, then you can get a backup of your database.

For example:
You can run a cron every 5 minutes(depending on how often you need a backup) and check if the latest record was added in the last 5 minutes. If yes, run the mysqldump command to get the backup.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you create master/slave setup. Periodically you take the slave down and make a copy of the database using rsync. Alternatively, you can leave the slave up and do a mysqldump, but that takes a lot longer to restore.